# How to compare two files in Python when line indices differ and regular expression has multiple matches?

Tags: regex, list, python-3.x, nested-loops

I have two files that I want to compare. They are all pretty long, but their basic structure is this:

```
trigger_file_org = '''
   10.792001    283292  30
   11.286001    296136   9
   11.792001    309292 130
   17.898001    468048  23
   18.390001    480840   9
   18.896001    493996 123
   24.988001    652388  73
   25.482001    665232   9
   25.988001    678388 173
   34.026002    887376  10
   34.518002    900168   9
   35.024002    913324 110
   40.676002   1060276  82
   41.170002   1073120   9
   41.676002   1086276 182
   48.994002   1276544  43
   49.488002   1289388   9
   49.994002   1302544 143
   56.032003   1459532  30
   56.524003   1472324   9
   57.032003   1485532 130
       '''
trigger_file = trigger_file_org.readlines()  

new_scenario_org = '''
30 7503
23 6412
73 1307
10 3901
82 4118
43 7404
30 3403
'''
scenario = new_scenario_org.readlines()
```

Now, the order of the two-digit codes in the first column of the scenario file is the same as the order of the two-digit codes in the last column of the trigger file (30 -> 23 -> 73 -> 10 -> 82 -> 43 -> 30), but in the trigger file there are other numbers in between, and the distance is not always the same.
Moreover, the two-digit codes will repeat eventually, so they do not identify a row uniquely.

What I want to do is compare the lines of the two files in descending order, and when the two-digit codes from the trigger file are found and matched, I want the four-digit codes from the scenario file be attached to that line, like this:

```
   10.792001    283292  30 7503
   11.286001    296136   9
   11.792001    309292 130
   17.898001    468048  23 6412
   18.390001    480840   9
   18.896001    493996 123
   24.988001    652388  73 1307
   25.482001    665232   9
   25.988001    678388 173
   34.026002    887376  10 3901
   34.518002    900168   9
   35.024002    913324 110
   40.676002   1060276  82 4118
   41.170002   1073120   9
   41.676002   1086276 182
   48.994002   1276544  43 4704
   49.488002   1289388   9
   49.994002   1302544 143
   56.032003   1459532  30 3403
   56.524003   1472324   9
   57.032003   1485532 130
```

So far the code I have is:

```
iterations = 0
trig_item_count = 0

    for trig_i in range(len(trigger_file)):
        curr_trigger_line = str.split(trigger_file[trig_i])
        #print(curr_trigger_line)
        if re.match('^[1-9][0-9]$', curr_trigger_line[2]):
            trig_item_count = trig_item_count + 1
            for sce_i in range(len(scenario)):
                iterations = iterations + 1   # this is 129 600 total in the end bc it iterates through the trigger file and then the scenario file
                curr_sce_line = str.split(scenario[sce_i])
                if curr_trigger_line[2] == curr_sce_line[0]:
                    line_where_match__was_found = trig_i
                    if trig_i > line_where_match__was_found:
                    print("Hurray")
```

This code finds all the occurrences of the two-digit code, but it iterates through the entire scenario file every time. I understand why this is wrong, but I don't know how to tell Python to do the search in a descending order and to ignore the occurrences that have already been matched.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger = '''\
   10.792001    283292  30
   11.286001    296136   9
   11.792001    309292 130
   17.898001    468048  23
   18.390001    480840   9
   18.896001    493996 123
   24.988001    652388  73
   25.482001    665232   9
   25.988001    678388 173
   34.026002    887376  10
   34.518002    900168   9
   35.024002    913324 110
   40.676002   1060276  82
   41.170002   1073120   9
   41.676002   1086276 182
   48.994002   1276544  43
   49.488002   1289388   9
   49.994002   1302544 143
   56.032003   1459532  30
   56.524003   1472324   9
   57.032003   1485532 130
'''.splitlines()

scenario = '''\
30 7503
23 6412
73 1307
10 3901
82 4118
43 7404
30 3403
'''.splitlines()

it = iter(scenario)


out = []
for line in trigger:
    if line[-3] == ' ' and line[-2] != ' ':
        key = line[-2:]
        try:
            key2, extra = next(it).split()
        except StopIteration:
            raise ValueError('scenario ended too soon')
        if key2 != key:
            raise ValueError('scenario key does not match')
        line += ' ' + extra
    out.append(line)

for line in out:
    print(line)
# matches your desired output as given
```